# posts_per_page not working on my Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to limit my posts from my custom post type but it's displaying all the posts. I want to limit the posts by 3. I've tried all the possible solutions from the **Stackoverflow**

**Here's the code:**

```
<?php   global $post;
            wp_reset_query();
            $args = array( 
            'posts_per_page' => 3, 
            'post_type' => 'services',
            'orderby' => 'date', 
            'order' => 'DESC', 
            'update_post_term_cache' => false, 
            'update_post_meta_cache' => false, 
            'nopaging' => true, 
        );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
```

Am I missing anything here?

Any suggestion will be appreciated !!

Comment: Remove  `'nopaging'`, if you pass `true` then show all posts . Default value is 'false', use paging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*posts_per_page* is pagination parameter but by using *'nopaging' => true* you disabled the pagination.

try this snippet instead

```
<?php   global $post;
        wp_reset_query();
        $args = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => 3, 
        'post_type' => 'services',
        'orderby' => 'date', 
        'order' => 'DESC', 
        'update_post_term_cache' => false, 
        'update_post_meta_cache' => false 
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
?>
```

For more details read section ['Pagination Parameters'](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) in WordPress Codex